# How to achieve a scroll fade effect in Corvid?

Tags: velo

I was wondering if it's possible to achieve a "scroll fade" effect using Corvid?

Here is an example (see the small arrow at the bottom of the page, and how it behaves when the page is scrolled down):  https://vero.co/

Here is my site, where I would like to achieve the same effect: https://www.notenoughknife.com/

I appreciate anybody who can help - I'm not the best at coding, so the more specific the code, the better!

Thanks in advance,

Matt

Comment: It looks like you may have already figured it out, but for anyone looking at this in the future, it's actually just a setting on the Wix Elements. You don't need code to achieve these effects. You can enable things like parallax effects and fade on scroll using the settings icon on the UI element itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have to add a little code for this.

For the code to work, you need to add two empty boxes (containers), make them transparent.

The basic idea here is that on scrolling when the box below the arrow appears on the screen, the arrow will be hidden, and when the top box appears on the screen, the arrow will be shown.

Place one slightly below the arrow so that on scroll when the box appears, the arrow should disappear. Put the other one at the top of the first image. Name the id in the editor as shown in the code or change accordingly. Put the code below in the onReady() section.

```
let fadeOptions = {
    "duration": 500, //time in ms
}
$w("#boxOverFirstImage").onViewportEnter(()=>{
    $w("#arrow").show("fade", fadeOptions);
});

$w("#boxBelowArrow").onViewportEnter(()=>{
    $w("#arrow").hide("fade", fadeOptions);
});
```

BTW when opening your site, the arrow is way down. I'm guessing you're using a wide-screen monitor. As most people will be using 1366 x 768 screens, you might need to bring it up a bit.

Comment: Absolutely perfect, thankyou very much. It took some time for me to understand everything, but I got there in the end! What a great person you are. And I'll look into the arrow position, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: ✌ My pleasure!